# Atm im just trying to get the total to come through

Tags: java

```
//total=airfair +carrental + parkingfees + confreg + taxifees + (lodging * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip)
//totalAllowable = airfair +carrental + parkingfees + confreg + taxifees + (lodging * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip) - 
public class TravelExpenses {

//variables
    private int daysOnTrip;
    private double airfair;
    private double carRentalFees;
    private double gasCost;
    private double milesDriven;
    private double parkingFees;
    private double taxiCharge;
    private double confRegFees;
    private double lodgingCharges;
    private double totalAllowable;
    private double totalExpenses = 0;
    private double amountSaved;
    private double totalExcess;

    //const variables
    private final double meals = 37;
    private final double parkingCov = 10.00;
    private final double taxiCov = 20.00;
    private final double lodgingCov = 95.00;
    private final double mileCov = 0.27;

    public TravelExpenses (int tripDays, double airCost, double     carRent, double miles, double parking, double taxi, double  confFees, double lodging) {
    daysOnTrip = tripDays;
    airfair = airCost;
    carRentalFees = carRent;
    milesDriven = miles;
    parkingFees = parking;
    taxiCharge = taxi;
    confRegFees = confFees;
    lodgingCharges = lodging;
}

public int getdaysOnTrip () {
    return daysOnTrip;
}

public double getairfair(){
    return airfair;
}
public double getcarRentalFees(){
    return carRentalFees;
}
public double getmilesDriven(){
    return milesDriven;
}
public double getparkingFees(){
    return parkingFees;
}
public double gettaxiCharge(){
    return taxiCharge;
}
public double getconfRegFees(){
    return confRegFees;
}
public double getlodgingCharges(){
    return lodgingCharges;
}

public double getgasCost(){
    return milesDriven * mileCov;
}

public double gettotalExpenses() {
    return airfair + carRentalFees + gasCost + parkingFees + confRegFees + taxiCharge + (lodgingCharges * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip);
}

}
```

So this is the class I think is what you would call it. Im not sure if I've done this right because the other one we did had setX() as a method but i dont know if it belongs in this one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TravelExpensesTest {
public static void main(String[] args){

//variables//
int daysOnTrip;
double airfair;
double carRentalFees;
double gasCost;
double milesDriven;
double parkingFees;
double taxiCharge;
double confRegFees;
double lodgingCharges;
double totalAllowable;
double totalExpenses = 0;
double amountSaved;
double totalExcess;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Number of days on the trip: ");
daysOnTrip = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Amount of Airfair: ");
airfair = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Amount of car rental: ");
carRentalFees = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Miles driven (If private vehicle was used: )");
milesDriven = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Parking Fees: ");
parkingFees = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Taxi Fees");
taxiCharge = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Conference Registration Fees");
confRegFees = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Lodging Charges (per night)");
lodgingCharges = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Total Expenses: " + totalExpenses + ".");
}
```

}
This is what actually executes everything. Once again not sure if i did this right because we did a payroll one where there was this Payroll pay = new Payroll(EmployeeName, IDNumber) and idk if i need that in this program too.

Any help is appreciated. Also new to coding and stackoverflow so if i goofed something up, help me help you :).

Comment: Hi Beej, Welcome to the programming world. Could you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your test class does not seem to be using the `TravelExpenses ` class.  You are supposed to use this class then call `gettotalExpenses` I think.

Comment: Sorry I meant to put it in there, anyways it's a travel expense program and currently im just trying to see if the total expenses display correctly but they dont.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing the calling of the `TravelExpenses` object inside your `TravelExpensesTest` class and providing the values through it's paremetized constructor. I have simplified (removed the keyboard input part) in your implementation to make it more evident. You can add your keyboard scanner part and it should work fine now. I hope it makes sense for you. :)

```java
//total=airfair +carrental + parkingfees + confreg + taxifees + (lodging * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip)
//totalAllowable = airfair +carrental + parkingfees + confreg + taxifees + (lodging * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip) - 

public class TravelExpensesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //variables//
        int     daysOnTrip = 1;
        double airfair = 1.0D;
        double carRentalFees = 1.0D;
        double milesDriven = 1.0D;
        double parkingFees = 1.0D;
        double taxiCharge = 1.0D;
        double confRegFees = 1.0D;
        double lodgingCharges = 1.0D;
        double totalAllowable;
        double amountSaved;
        double totalExcess;
        
        TravelExpenses travelExpenses = new TravelExpenses(daysOnTrip, airfair, carRentalFees, milesDriven, parkingFees, taxiCharge, confRegFees, lodgingCharges); // you needed to call this, Beej.
        double totalExpenses = travelExpenses.getTotalExpenses(); // when you call the `.getTotalExpenses()` on your `travelExpenses` object, that's when it will calculate and give you the answer.
        System.out.println("Total Expenses: " + totalExpenses + ".");
    }
}

class TravelExpenses {

    //variables
    private int daysOnTrip;
    private double airfair;
    private double carRentalFees;
    private double gasCost;
    private double milesDriven;
    private double parkingFees;
    private double taxiCharge;
    private double confRegFees;
    private double lodgingCharges;
    private double totalAllowable;
    private double totalExpenses = 0;
    private double amountSaved;
    private double totalExcess;

    //const variables
    private final double meals = 37;
    private final double parkingCov = 10.00;
    private final double taxiCov = 20.00;
    private final double lodgingCov = 95.00;
    private final double mileCov = 0.27;

    public TravelExpenses(int tripDays, double airCost, double carRent, double miles, double parking, double taxi, double confFees, double lodging) {
        daysOnTrip = tripDays;
        airfair = airCost;
        carRentalFees = carRent;
        milesDriven = miles;
        parkingFees = parking;
        taxiCharge = taxi;
        confRegFees = confFees;
        lodgingCharges = lodging;
    }

    public int getdaysOnTrip() {
        return daysOnTrip;
    }

    public double getairfair() {
        return airfair;
    }
    public double getcarRentalFees() {
        return carRentalFees;
    }
    public double getmilesDriven() {
        return milesDriven;
    }
    public double getparkingFees() {
        return parkingFees;
    }
    public double gettaxiCharge() {
        return taxiCharge;
    }
    public double getconfRegFees() {
        return confRegFees;
    }
    public double getlodgingCharges() {
        return lodgingCharges;
    }

    public double getgasCost() {
        return milesDriven * mileCov;
    }

    public double getTotalExpenses() {
        return airfair + carRentalFees + gasCost + parkingFees + confRegFees + taxiCharge + (lodgingCharges * daysOnTrip) + (meals * daysOnTrip);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had used it before I just couldn't remember if that was what it was. So to make totalAllowable come through I would need to make a new TravelExpenses class with the parameters set to calculate that since they differ from the ones needed to get the totalExpenses?